# by using AV foundation or other tool kits on iOS is it possible to get an event function to fire on every frame captured?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

In either swift or objective-C code is there any way to get a function to fire either just before or just after a video frame is captured?

I could use the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` but is there a better way?

The reason I want to be able to have a function fire just before or just after a frame is recorded to disk is so that I can have adjustments done to the camera on a frame by frame basis.

I don't need the full image processing pipeline offered by `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`. I'd really rather just depend on the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` because its a lot simpler to make it work and I suspect that saving right to disk instead of branching off the samples here and there will be more ideal performance wise for my simple application.

Timers are really too inaccurate for my task. I tried quartz core events but I think my frame rate is limited to 60 fps and I need 240. Or 96 at least.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do it without the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

the best delegate method to use is the captureOutput : didOutputSampleBuffer overload method.

Apparently this overload method is fired as soon as a new buffer is available.